# Parsing result data of ZXING Barcode

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, barcode-scanner

Using ZXING Barcode component if I read this QRCode I get this VCARD:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGQgy.png): [image]

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:haluk
ORG:test
TITLE:12345
TEL:55533344121
END:VCARD
```

I just need the N and ORG values, is it possible to parse it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i just failed, i tried string.substring method like 15 char and take 5 char but if his name like qwertyuı? goes to down line , i just wish to parse example only ORG and TITLE value;

returns ;

test
12345

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: there is a problem, it have to way another way because if i search like "N:" ( name of raw) there is like 3 time like versioN:, begiN: must be find in from source code library, name of zXING

Comment: It should work like this: 1. take a line, 2. split on `:`, 3. check if you need the key, 4. write key and value. Please show any code you have tried.

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/iOS/Sample.iOS/HomeViewController.cs

this is source, and i just try to linq query

         var resultcccc = from s in result.Text.StartsWith("P:") select s;
 or containts or something but i  just .. fail..

Comment: That's sample code, not your code; show some of your own code, in the question. Voting to close.

Comment: Let's reopen this question. There is a valid answer and the question makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ZXing contains a ResultParser class which does the job for you.
Here is an example for ZXing.Net (C#):

```
// "result" is an instance of the barcode scanning result
var parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result) as AddressBookParsedResult;
if (parsedResult != null)
{
   // N value
   var nValue = parsedResult.Names;
   // ORG value
   var orgValue = parsedResult.Org;
   // do something with the values
   ...
}
```

Comment: dude, i had to tell you are real a super hero ! :) Thanks,

Comment: The best way to show your appreciation (and help fellow SO users) is to mark the question as answered (green checkmark) and to upvote the answer(s) that were helpful to you.